# Using Fragments in ActionBar Tabs to have widgets

Tags: android, android-widget, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-tabs

I made a program that uses [FragmentTabs](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/FragmentTabs.html) for implementing `ActionBar` `Tabs`.

I was wondering how it is possible to add a widget to a inflated `Fragments` in `Tabs`. It's more complicated than normal because the fragment is returning only an `onCreateView` to the `TabListener`, so how would I add in functioning widgets? I don't need specific code, just the logic please!

Here is a sample `Fragment` being `inflated` when a `Tab` is clicked (inside of which I need widgets):

```
public class IdFragment extends Fragment{       
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.id_layout, container, false);
    }
}
```